# show that $\mathsf E(Y|X)=\mu_2+\rho\dfrac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}(X-\mu_1)$

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ have a joint distribution with finite means and variances respectively given by $\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2$ with correlation coefficient given by $\rho$.

Further suppose that $\mathsf E(Y|X)$ is a linear function in $X$.

I have to show that $\mathsf E(Y|X)=\mu_2+\rho\dfrac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}(X-\mu_1)$.

I also have to then show that $\mathsf E(\mathsf {Var}(Y|X))=\sigma_2^2(1-\rho^2)$.

Comment: I've edited this using MathJax as best I could interpret the original post. Please edit it to correct any misunderstanding; it wasn't clear.

Comment: Except for the p part. it is p*(o2/o1) and then all of that * (X-u1). So the u2 is not supposed to be a part of the fraction @GrahamKemp

Comment: Any better now?

Answer (score 2):

Let $E[Y|X] = aX +b$. Taking expectations w.r.t X,
$$E_X[E[Y|X]] = aE[X] + b$$
$$E[Y] = aE[X] + b$$
Therefore,
$$\mu_2 = a\mu_1 + b \quad (1)$$
Now, taking variance of $E[Y|X]$ w.r.t X,
$$Var_X[E[Y|X]] = a^2Var_X[X] \quad (2)$$
Rewriting E[Y|X] we get,
$$E[Y|X] - aX = b$$
Taking variance w.r.t X, we get,
$$Var_X[E[Y|X]] + a^2Var[X] - 2aCov(X, E[Y|X]) = 0$$
Now, 
$$Cov(X, E[Y|X]) = E[XE[Y|X]] - E[X]E_X[E[Y|X]] = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = Cov(X, Y)$$
Therefore,
$$Var_X[E[Y|X]] = 2aCov(X, Y) - a^2Var[X] \quad (3)$$
Comparing (2) and (3), we get,
$$a = \frac{Cov(X, Y)}{Var[X]} = \rho\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1} \quad (4)$$
From (1) and (4), we get,
$$b = \mu_2 - \rho\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}\mu_1$$
Substituting back a and b, we get,
$$E[Y|X] = \mu_2 + \rho\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1} (X - \mu_1)$$

For the next part, use law of total variance and result is obtained.